# Cannot do any go command anymore

Tags: go, command-line-interface, homebrew, godeps, gopath

Before it happened, what I am doing is trying to use the **dep** to manage my **golang** code dependency.
What I found right now is I cannot do any command with **go**, even if I try to uninstall it with **brew** by `brew uninstall go` and do `brew install go` again.

If I am doing a `go env` it will show like this:

```
$ go env
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/cellar/go/1.13.1/libexec

$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.8/libexec/
CONTRIBUTING.md SECURITY.md bin     lib     robots.txt
CONTRIBUTORS    VERSION     doc     misc        src
PATENTS     api     favicon.ico pkg     test

$ go version
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/cellar/go/1.13.1/libexec

$ go build
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/cellar/go/1.13.1/libexec

$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/mymac/go

$ echo $GOROOT

$
```

What should I do and check?

Comment: Do not install Go via brew. Use the official Go distribution from golang.org. And do not use dep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

> https://gist.github.com/vsouza/77e6b20520d07652ed7d
>
> ```
> # Set variables in .bashrc file
>
> # don't forget to change your path correctly!
> export GOPATH=$HOME/golang
> export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
> export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
> export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
> ```

Of course, you'll need to change "$HOME/golang" and "/usr/local/opt/go: to your actual path names.

---

From OP:

> finally i solve this, can you help to update your comment  then i will
>   set it as SOLVED.
>
> i use
>
> `export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.8/libexec/`
>
> instead of
>
> `GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec`

Comment: Well, i don't think GOPATH should point to GO binary path. GOPATH is where maintanable sour source code is residing.

Comment: Fair enough.  See my revised comments

Comment: finally i solve this, can you help to update your comment?
i use export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.8/libexec/ instead of GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
then i will set it as SOLVED.

Answer (score 45):

I personally use this for Homebrew

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
# Homebrew
export GOROOT="$(brew --prefix golang)/libexec"
# Manual install
# export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

[Blogpost](https://hantri.blogspot.com/2023/03/golang-setup-path.html)

Comment: `export GOROOT="$(brew --prefix golang)/libexec"` saved my day.

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks.